# Constraint to update values if primary key matches in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

`This is the sample query:`

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (ID, NAME, AGE, SALARY, ADDRESS)    
VALUES (1, 'Paul', 30, '1550.00', 'Ahmedabad')   

`if ID matches`  
then i want to UPDATE  the table
NAME='Paul', AGE=30,SALARY='1550.00', 
ADDRESS='Ahmedabad'
```

`ID` is the unique index column in the table.

I want to insert a new row if id does not match and if id matched then update the rest of the column.

Comment: is there any way of using on conflict while creating table like ignore duplicate constraint or primary key constraint.. because i have multiple primary keys in the table and i am inserting the records dynamically using c# code

Comment: Here you can read about and study the [proper syntax for `INSERT` in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)